# How to stop observe

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code for retrieving data from Firebase database. The code works fine, but it retrieves the same data multiple times.

How do I stop observe so that the data will only be called once

My code

```
self.eventGalleryImage.child("event")
                            .child(self.eventName.text!)
                            .child("EventImages")
                            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for child in snapshots {
            if let dict = child.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let userGallery = dict["Text"] as? String {                                                      
                    self.postsFindGallery.insert(galleryStruct(gallery: userGallery), at: 0)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you read the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ ? It kind of explains it all, or does it not? There are sections about subscribing, listeners, detaching listeners, retrieving the value once ...

Comment: Every time you call `observeSingleEvent`, the callback will be called at most once. If you're seeing the code being called multiple times, you're likely calling `observeSingleEvent` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

A lesson to be learnt. Do all you can to avoid using for loops when observing data. This is what you'll need to do to get all of the data inside that database path ONCE:

```
self.eventGalleryImage.child("event")
    .child(self.eventName.text!)
    .child("EventImages")
    .observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
        if let userGallery = dictionary["Text"] as? String {
            self.postsFindGallery.insert(galleryStruct(gallery: userGallery), at: 0)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
```

You may also want to try:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @CarstenHøvsgaard Glad to help! If this helped you out, I’d really appreciate a vote or a mark as answer. If you have anymore questions, feel free to ask!